# Could not create task 'clean': Unknown argument(s) in task definition: [typec] in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

Whenever i build **flutter build apk --release** then below issue is shown in Android Studio

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not create task 'clean': Unknown argument(s) in task definition: [typec]